# Stop JS when browser stop button or ESC is pressed

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser

So I have this page which loads an iframe with external content (different domain).
Now the following script part loads another JS function 5 seconds after the iframe loads:

```
document.getElementById('" . $hash . "').onload = function() {
window.setTimeout('kernelInit(\'" . $hash . "\')', 5000);
     if ($(this).height() == 0) {
     window.location = 'stop.html';
     }
     if ($(this).width() == 0) {
     window.location = 'stop.html';
     }
};
```

All good till now. However users can click the browser stop button or press the ESC key thus preventing the iframe content to load completely or at all. So the above JS check is rendered useless since it cannot check if the iframe content was loaded at all nor if the users stopped the loading manually.

I know there must be a solution for this. Perhaps creating then checking for a connection between user and server every X ms? which theoretically if cancelled (by the browser stop button or ESC key) should cancel further loading of any javascript.
Goal here is to NOT finish the above script if the navigation gets stopped or cancelled.

Any pointers?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to load another page in an iframe?

Comment: Ads are shown in the iframe. Users get incentives for viewing those ads. If the users stop the loading of the ads then we have a problem.

Comment: Frames being loaded doesn't necessarily mean the ads are being displayed. Just fyi the users can hide them with some custom CSS. An alternative way would be to fetch the content through XHR via your server or another server with cross domain allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that for the Esc option

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
        alert("Esc was pressed")
    }
});
```

For the cancel button of the browser I don't know how to do.
Change the alert to the event you want to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/aLot1mky/